# Upgrade Path for Apache Nifi

Tags: java, java-8, apache-nifi

Any tips for upgrading an Apache Nifi instance? We were thinking we would do something similar to the following:

1. Deploy the latest Nifi versions to our running instances.
2. Deploy any custom NARs to the updated version.
3. Make sure to drain the existing Nifi instance.
4. Shutdown current Nifi instances.
5. Start new Nifi instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outline you write should work just fine.  You should be able to skip the step about draining the queues.  It is designed to simply restore those.  Be sure to also copy over any customized content of your previous install conf folder to the new install folder.  Most importantly copy over the flow xml.  The idea is that you  should be able to upgrade within seconds and have the same flow and all data retained.  Now, we need to do a much better of job of making that not so much of an exercise to the reader as it is today.  We need to help automate that and we need to document the various cases one should consider.

As you work through it feel free to let us know.  We can also help at users@nifi.apache.org but will also try to keep an eye out here.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Very cool. Thanks Joe. I will add any relevant findings to this question and / or also submit addition to the email you posted in your response.

Comment: no problem.  We're also going to get an upgrade guide added to the build so it shows up with all the rest of the guides/admin info.  We want to make it as easy as possible to upgrade and it is a focus area for us going forward.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-590  Saw a draft of it the other day.  We need to get its patch in once it is in markdown form.

Comment: We did get the upgrade guide up:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Upgrading+NiFi